# Mozilla Eudora in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

Although manual installation is possible, can Mozilla's Eudora be integrated in Ubuntu 12.04 Software Center?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/firefox-aurora

Remember daily use is not guaranteed.

**PPA description**

This PPA contains builds of Firefox from the aurora channel

All users of this PPA are encouraged to report any bugs they find. Instructions for reporting bugs can be found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MozillaTeam/Bugs. Please have a read of this before reporting a bug, as it may help save time.

Please don't email the package uploader to report bugs. Not only is email not a good tool for tracking bugs, it also excludes anybody else from tracking or working on the issue.

If publishing is disabled for this PPA, there is no need to email the team or any of its members to tell them this. Publishing will be reneabled by a team member when it is appropriate to do so.